# How to read web content from the end

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to read web content from the end? I'm trying to fetch data from a 400 KB PHP file but the new information is at the end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you really want is to download a part of a file, see [Range Requests and Partial Responses](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html).